# How to Use gRPC with Protocol buffer with Django

Tags: python, django, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am using Django to make an E-commerce website and i want to use [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html) with [Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview), so, i can serve different client platform to like IOS, Android etc. i want to use gRPC because it is compatible with TensorFlow models to serve with live data of customers or using tensorflow models in productions 
I just want to know how to use in django, i am new to Django please help.

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question [if you shared the code that you're running and the error(s) that you're seeing](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html).

Comment: Just get started here : https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a gRPC toolkit for Django ([django-grpc-framework](https://github.com/fengsp/django-grpc-framework)) that helps you do the following things:

- gRPC server with a development mode (auto-reloader, checks) [server](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html)
- a service class that manages django db connection state [services](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services.html)
- a generic service that map closely to your db models [generics](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html)
- a simple proto generator based on model [proto generation](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protos.html)
- a simple `RPCTestCase` [testing](https://djangogrpcframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/testing.html)